# Image Morphing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I want to use mathematical morphology function in MATLAB to find the boundary of can.png image. The input image is:

[image]

I want to get a boundary such as :

[image]

I tried to use different combination and parameter using strel, imerode, imdilate , But the result is not good enough (far from the expectation)

One of my trial code is:

```
a = imread ('can.png');
b = im2bw(a);

SE = strel('rectangle', [10 50 ]) ;
i2 = imdilate(b,SE);

figure(1); imshow(i2);

p = ones(4);
c = b - imerode(b,p);

figure(2); imshow(c);
```

The output is:

[image]

Can any body help me, how to create the expected image (black background with thin boundary for the can, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: In what way is this image morphing ? Change your question's title to better reflect what you are after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binarize on its morphological gradient, then do a dilation with an elementary SE, fill holes and finally obtain its border (trivial given the current image). This doesn't require any magical arbitrary threshold.

[image] [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Binarize on its morphological gradient"? IN SE (using strel), we also need to determine which structure we use, and it's size.

Comment: @user1917485 morphological gradient is very commonly defined on dilation - erosion, with the elementary square. To binarize on it I mean to simply run otsu on the result to get the binarization threshold: `im2bw(mgrad, graythresh(mgrad))`. Here, if you really need Matlab syntax, SE is always equal to `strel(square, 3)`.

Comment: Thank you. I am a newbie, I have tried to implement this:

mgrad=imread ('can.png');
I = im2bw(mgrad, graythresh(mgrad));
se = strel('square',3);
c = imdilate(I, se) - imerode(I, se);
Imf = imfill(c, 'holes');
figure(3), imshow(Imf);    

But the can is filled by white pixels

Comment: `img = imread('can.png'); mgrad = imdilate(img, se) - imerode(img, se);` now you binarize on the morphological gradient. If the can is filled by white pixels then that is good, the only step left is the trivial one mentioned. It uses morphology too, do you want to think before I give it ?

Comment: By repeating one of the previous line, I get the fine result, right?

Comment: @user1917485 Suppose you saved the result of `imfill` in the binary can to `bcan`. What happens if you do `bcan - imerode(bcan, se)` ?

Comment: OK, It is better :), Thank you very much for the guidance and the discussion

Answer (score 4):

```
im = imread('can.png');

% turn image to BW
imb = (im < 220);

% fill the holes in the image
imf = imfill(imb, 'holes');

% find the edge
ed = edge(imf);
```

Resulting image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. The result is perfect. However, I want to learn mathematical morphology function in MATLAB by using strel, imerode, and imdilate.